# How do I select an XML-node based on its content?

Tags: xml, xpath

How can I use XPath to select an XML-node based on its content?

If I e.g. have the following xml and I want to select the <author>-node that contains Ritchie to get the author's full name:

```
<books>
    <book isbn='0131103628'>
        <title>The C Programming Language</title>
        <authors>
            <author>Ritchie, Dennis M.</author>
            <author>Kernighan, Brian W.</author>
        </authors>
    </book>
    <book isbn='1590593898'>
        <title>Joel on Software</title>
        <authors>
            <author>Spolsky, Joel</author>
        </authors>
    </book>
</books>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
/books/book/authors/author[contains(., 'Ritchie')]
```

or

```
//author[contains(., 'Ritchie')]
```

Comment: For XPath newbies such as myself it might be valuable to note that the `.` is a shorter alias for `text()` - so yes, this answer does the right thing.

Comment: where could I read a complete and friendly reference of these functions?

Comment: @Oliver — This mention of `text()` did confuse me much. It is wrong. [The `.` is simply the current element.](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathpredicate.php)

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - Thanks for your comment and the link to the example. At the very end of the page they also write this: _Whenever you need to select an element and use a predicate on that same element you will need to use a period "." to access **that element's value**._ So yes, my mention of text() was not correct. As per **w3.org**: [. selects the context node and text() selects all text node children of the context node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev). And even [more examples using text()](http://www.xquery.com/tips_and_tricks/using_text_in_XPath.html).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when the target text has multiple lines.

Answer (score 4):

The XPath for this is:

```
/books/book/authors/author[contains(., 'Ritchie')]
```

In C# the following code would return "Ritchie, Dennis M.":

```
xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/books/book/authors/author[contains(., 'Ritchie')]").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//author[contains(text(), 'Ritchie')]
```